# "No default Dev Hub is set" when I already authorized a Dev Hub for Salesforce Development on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am getting an error message in VSCode when I am trying to create a scratch org for Salesforce Lightning Component development.

`No default Dev Hub is set. Run "SFDX: Authorize a Dev Hub" to set one.`

I already ran that command and have gotten successful messages.

`Successfully authorized <mylogin> with org ID <id>...ended with exit code 0`

I am stuck at this part and no matter how many times I authorize a dev hub, I'm unable to create a scratch org.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211854/salesforce-dx-how-to-set-default-devhub-if-i-missed-the-d-option-when-connect) you have to use the -d flag to set the Dev Hub as a default one or set the defaultdevhubusername variable.

Hope it helps.